# Why every time i need to map folder in team foundation server?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I am using TFS2015 and VS2010 ultimate.
I map a solution from solution explorer to my local folder. Now when I restart my system. I need to map that project to my local folder again. Why is this happening. And when I tried to map again then got the error that project already mapped.

Comment: Are you definitely in the same workspace after the re-boot.  Can you see the original in the drop down?  With 2010 it should be a server workspace.  Have you got VS2010 SP1 and the Compat GDR (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/tfs/administer/requirements)

Comment: How did you map a solution from Solution Explorer? Can you see the mapping information under Source Control Explorer? After restarting your system, have you connected to TFS before checking the mapping information?

Comment: @rerwinRR, I am in the same workspace and Also have VS2010SP1.

Comment: @Cece I am map from Source Control Explorer and Connected to TFS before checking the mapping information. :-(

Comment: @RaviAgrawal, please try the following simple code to check whether the workspace is created correctly.

Answer (score 0):

1). Use the following code to check whether workspace is created successfully:

```
        TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("tfsURL"));
        VersionControlServer vcs = (VersionControlServer)tpc.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));
        Workspace ws = vcs.GetWorkspace("$/teamproject");
        string workspacename = ws.Name;
```

2). If the workspace is created successfully, however, you still get the "project already mapped" message, then please firstly clean the local TFS cache and then re-connect again. To clean TFS cache, delete the "%localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\6.0\Cache\" folder.